# Why Google document viewer is not rendering some files?

Tags: html, ms-word, preview, google-document-viewer

When I try to preview document from google viewer. I  get errors like

> There was a problem previewing this document.

OR

> There was a problem displaying this image.

Here is the Live URL
https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://wikisoftpedia.com/evento_fyp/small_file.docx

Some of the files are rendering like 
https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://wikisoftpedia.com/evento_fyp/experience.docx

What is the issue?

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try to encode your URL with `encodeURIComponent('your url here')`